# Adding a feature to a neuron

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

Say I have the following model:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1, 5)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(5, 10)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(10, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        print(x) 
        x = torch.relu(x)        
        x = torch.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x

net = Model()

opt = optim.Adam(net.parameters())
features = torch.rand((3,1)) #3 inputs, each of 1D
```

I can print the value of my neurons (only the first layer here) with `print(x)`:

```
net(features)
>>>tensor([[ 0.6703,  0.4484, -0.8529,  1.3119,  0.6741],
        [ 0.9112,  0.6496, -1.2960,  1.8264,  0.4547],
        [ 0.7483,  0.5135, -0.9963,  1.4785,  0.6031]],
       grad_fn=<AddmmBackward>)
tensor([[0.0144],
        [0.0575],
        [0.0284]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward>)
```

How can I add a "feature" to each neuron that is a string with a name?
e.g.

```
print(x)
>>> tensor([[ [0.6703, 'neuron_1'],  [0.4484, 'neuron_2'], [-0.8529, 'neuron_3'],  1.3119,  0.6741],... etc.
```

I'm not sure if I'll need to change the `neuron` class. I believe in the forward method I will then need to only take the first element of each neurons tensor: `neuron_tensor = [neuron_value, neuron_name]`

**Update 1:**
from @Aditya Singh Rathore comment it sounds like it might not be possible to have a string and a value in the same tensor. Is it possible then to have a value instead of a string to represent the neurons?

From before `neuron_tensor = [neuron_value, neuron_name]` where `neuron_name` is a string.
Is this possible instead? : `neuron_tensor = [neuron_value, neuron_name]` where `neuron_name` is just a value (e.g `1` for neuron 1, `2` for neuron 2)

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Each tensor has a data type. You might have to define a tuple, `(float,string)`. Best way would be use `NN.parameters` and create customs layers

Comment: I have passed custom classes as `dtype` to numpy array, with overloaded `__sub__`, `__mul__` and `__add__`. This is very slow. But you could try something like this and create custom `tensors`. This is one way, though not recommended. It could be tuple (value,Id)

Comment: Can you guide me on how to create a tensor of size 2 per neuron and to take only the first component in the forward method? I can do the id on my own I believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is possible, although I'm not sure what you exactly want to do with this. Basically you seem to want to include the "index" in the intermediate tensor for some purpose, and again discard it when passing to the next layer.

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1, 5)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(5, 10)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(10, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        idx_tensor = (torch.arange(x.shape[1]) + 1).unsqueeze(0).repeat_interleave(repeats=x.shape[0], dim=0)
        x = torch.cat([x.unsqueeze(2), idx_tensor.unsqueeze(2)], dim=2)
        print(x)
        
        x = torch.relu(x[:, :, 0])    
        x = torch.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
```

Running this gives:

```
net = Model()

opt = optim.Adam(net.parameters())
features = torch.rand((3,1))
net(features)

>>>tensor([[[ 0.0817,  1.0000],
         [ 0.8084,  2.0000],
         [ 1.6118,  3.0000],
         [ 0.8658,  4.0000],
         [-0.1583,  5.0000]],

        [[ 0.2881,  1.0000],
         [ 0.6946,  2.0000],
         [ 1.3760,  3.0000],
         [ 0.6098,  4.0000],
         [-0.1240,  5.0000]],

        [[ 0.1919,  1.0000],
         [ 0.7476,  2.0000],
         [ 1.4859,  3.0000],
         [ 0.7291,  4.0000],
         [-0.1400,  5.0000]]], grad_fn=<CatBackward>)

tensor([[-0.2841],
        [-0.2191],
        [-0.2495]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward>)
```

Note that a typical tensor cannot be both integer and float at the same time, so the 1, 2, 3 will be stored as float 1.000.., 2.000... etc.

I suggest if your purpose is something like a fancy printing, then maybe look into torch's hook functions? For example, you can do something like:

```
import pandas as pd

def fc_hook_fn(module, input, output):
    print("\n" + "#" * 60)
    print(f"In layer {module}")
    print("#" * 60 + "\n")
    cols = [f"Neuron-{i + 1}" for i in range(output.shape[1])]
    idx = [f"Input-{i + 1}" for i in range(output.shape[0])]
    neuron_activations = pd.DataFrame(output.detach().numpy(), columns=cols, index=idx)
    print(neuron_activations)

net.fc.register_forward_hook(fc_hook_fn)
```

Now each time something passes through fc1, the function above will be triggered. You don't need to put your print(x) in the forward method.

```
############################################################
In layer Linear(in_features=1, out_features=5, bias=True)
############################################################

         Neuron-1  Neuron-2  Neuron-3  Neuron-4  Neuron-5
Input-1 -0.948735 -0.901034 -0.290353 -0.082616 -0.405337
Input-2 -0.725904 -0.801648 -0.302922 -0.045514 -0.580485
Input-3 -0.829738 -0.847960 -0.297065 -0.062802 -0.498870
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Not sure what you mean by "discard it when passing to the next layer". Is there a way to maintain these indices so that I can access them later? Similarly to how you can access the neurons after training

Comment: By discard, I meant that these indices have no use in the training process, and are not passed to `fc2`. You can definitely maintain indices inside the model for later access, maybe something as simple as self.idx = idx_tensor would do.